# How to use "mathds" along with "mathdesign" package in LaTeX?

Tags: pdftex

How to use `\mathds{k}` in LaTeX while using `\usepackage[bitstream-charter, cal=cmcal]{mathdesign}` ? I have included `\usepackage{dsfont}`, but it is showing error and the `mathds font` is not processing. I am using `amsart` as document class.

Any suggestion to resolve this?

Comment: Can you post a `MWE` of your requirement?

Comment: The problem may be with the ordering of packages, please try with `\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage[bitstream-charter, cal=cmcal]{mathdesign}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\begin{document}

Test $\mathds{k}$
\end{document}`, this works fine for me...If still the error exists, please post a `MWE`